# Set horizontal bar graph width for single value using matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Kindly help with limiting the width of a horizontal bar graph **with single value** plotted using **barh** in matplotlib & python3:-
The problem is with one or two values the width of each bar covers complete height of the graph.

I want the bar width to be fixed whether there are 10 values or 1 value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ylim`. Detailed information can be found in the documentation: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.ylim.html . This should fix the issue of matplotlib ignoring the width argument when only plotting one value.

If you give ylim a negative value as first argument, it will show some space between the x-axis and the bar, if you'd like to:
e.g. `plt.ylim(-0.5,12)`

If there's more than just one value, the `width` argument should just do the work.

How the code looks like:

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
  
labels = ['SomeLabel'] 
  
data = [21] 

width = 0.2 # which is actually the height from this point of view

plt.plot()
plt.barh(labels, data, width) 

plt.ylim(0, 5)

plt.show()
```

Comment: thank u so much, it was indeed a great help!

Comment: You are absolutely welcome, feel free to accept this answer as soon as you're able to, so it helps other readers as well ;)